# ipyparallel - 'CannedFunction' object is not callable

Tags: python, ipython, starcluster

I am trying to set up a cluster using [StarCluster](http://star.mit.edu/cluster/) and ipyparallel. When I try to run the following commands, I get the error below. I have never seen a python error
missing a stack trace this way.

```
from ipyparallel import Client
rc = Client()
ipview = rc[:]
res = ipview.apply_async(lambda x: x+3, 3)
res.get()
```

I get the following error:

```
[0:apply]: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)<string> in <module>()
TypeError: 'CannedFunction' object is not callable

[1:apply]: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)<string> in <module>()
TypeError: 'CannedFunction' object is not callable
```

Not even sure where to start debugging this.

It would be helpful if anyone knows why there isn't really a Traceback with the error. I have never seen this kind of traceback before.

Here is the output from pip freeze on the master node

```
apt-xapian-index==0.45
backports-abc==0.4
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.5.0.1
boto==2.3.0
certifi==2016.2.28
chardet==2.0.1
Cheetah==2.4.4
cloud-init==0.7.2
configobj==4.7.2
Cython==0.17.4
decorator==4.0.9
distro-info==0.10
Django==1.6.1
docutils==0.10
drmaa==0.7.5
dumbo==0.21.36
euca2ools==2.1.1
futures==3.0.5
ipykernel==4.3.1
ipyparallel==5.0.1
ipython==4.0.0
ipython-cluster-helper==0.5.1
ipython-genutils==0.1.0
Jinja2==2.6
jupyter-client==4.2.1
jupyter-core==4.1.0
Landscape-Client==13.7.3
M2Crypto==0.21.1
Mako==0.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.15
matplotlib==1.2.1
meld3==0.6.10
mercurial==2.2.2
mpi4py==1.3.1
multiprocessing==2.6.2.1
netifaces==0.10.4
nose==1.1.2
numexpr==2.0.1
numpy==1.8.0
oauth==1.0.1
openpyxl==1.5.8
PAM==0.4.2
pandas==0.12.0
paramiko==1.7.7.1
path.py==8.1.2
pexpect==4.0.1
pickleshare==0.6
Pillow==2.3.0
prettytable==0.6.1
pssh==2.2.2
ptyprocess==0.5.1
pudb==2013.5.1
pycrypto==2.6
pycurl==7.19.0
Pygments==1.6
pyOpenSSL==0.13
pyparsing==1.5.7
pyserial==2.6
python-apt===0.8.8ubuntu6
python-dateutil==1.5
python-debian===0.1.21-nmu2ubuntu1
python-distutils-extra==2.37
pytz==2012rc0
PyYAML==3.10
pyzmq==15.2.0
requests==1.1.0
roman==1.4.0
scipy==0.13.2
simplegeneric==0.8.1
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.10.0
Sphinx==1.1.3
ssh-import-id==3.14
statsmodels==0.4.2
supervisor==3.0
tables==2.4.0
tornado==4.3
traitlets==4.1.0
Twisted-Core==12.3.0
Twisted-Names==12.3.0
Twisted-Web==12.3.0
typedbytes==0.3.8
urllib3==1.5
urwid==1.1.2
virtualenv==1.11
xlrd==0.6.1
xlwt==0.7.4
zope.interface==4.0.5
```

Here is the pip freeze from the only slave node

```
apt-xapian-index==0.45
backports-abc==0.4
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.5.0.1
boto==2.3.0
certifi==2016.2.28
chardet==2.0.1
Cheetah==2.4.4
cloud-init==0.7.2
configobj==4.7.2
Cython==0.17.4
decorator==4.0.9
distro-info==0.10
Django==1.6.1
docutils==0.10
drmaa==0.7.5
dumbo==0.21.36
euca2ools==2.1.1
futures==3.0.5
ipykernel==4.3.1
ipyparallel==5.0.1
ipython==4.0.0
ipython-cluster-helper==0.5.1
ipython-genutils==0.1.0
Jinja2==2.6
jupyter-client==4.2.1
jupyter-core==4.1.0
Landscape-Client==13.7.3
M2Crypto==0.21.1
Mako==0.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.15
matplotlib==1.2.1
meld3==0.6.10
mercurial==2.2.2
mpi4py==1.3.1
multiprocessing==2.6.2.1
netifaces==0.10.4
nose==1.1.2
numexpr==2.0.1
numpy==1.8.0
oauth==1.0.1
openpyxl==1.5.8
PAM==0.4.2
pandas==0.12.0
paramiko==1.7.7.1
path.py==8.1.2
pexpect==4.0.1
pickleshare==0.6
Pillow==2.3.0
prettytable==0.6.1
pssh==2.2.2
ptyprocess==0.5.1
pudb==2013.5.1
pycrypto==2.6
pycurl==7.19.0
Pygments==1.6
pyOpenSSL==0.13
pyparsing==1.5.7
pyserial==2.6
python-apt===0.8.8ubuntu6
python-dateutil==1.5
python-debian===0.1.21-nmu2ubuntu1
python-distutils-extra==2.37
pytz==2012rc0
PyYAML==3.10
pyzmq==15.2.0
requests==1.1.0
roman==1.4.0
scipy==0.13.2
simplegeneric==0.8.1
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.10.0
Sphinx==1.1.3
ssh-import-id==3.14
statsmodels==0.4.2
supervisor==3.0
tables==2.4.0
tornado==4.3
traitlets==4.1.0
Twisted-Core==12.3.0
Twisted-Names==12.3.0
Twisted-Web==12.3.0
typedbytes==0.3.8
urllib3==1.5
urwid==1.1.2
virtualenv==1.11
xlrd==0.6.1
xlwt==0.7.4
zope.interface==4.0.5
```